# Proper way to satisfy liskov substitution principle?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

How should I properly satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle in this sample?

```py
class User(ABC):  # App core logic
    def add_photo(self, photo: bytes, ) -> None:
        ...


class FacebookUser(User):  # API interation logic
    def add_photo(self, photo: custom_type, ) -> None:
        ... # Set of Facebook specific actions.
        super().add_photo(photo=photo.bytes, )
```

I know 4 solutions:

1. Name mangling. Flaws:
   Forcing me to rename all the existing code with
   `Parent.add_photo` and probably all the rest methods.
2. Composition. Flaws:
   2.1. Can't reflect the logical relation between the classes.
   2.2 Forcing me to implement (proxy) methods for every `Parent` method.
3. `if` checking for the `self` object type inside the method. Flaws:
   3.1. Additional complexity and clumsy branches.
4. Implement `convert_photo` method from `custom_type` to `bytes` type inside the `FacebookUser` child class. Flaws:
   4.1 I still need to place a new `convert_photo` method inside some kinda "event" method (set of methods) and the best name for it is `add_photo`.

Comment: Is it a python specific question?

Comment: @PeterCsala Mostly not. Anyway, I used all the 5 hashtags, I can't add one more with "Python".

Comment: I think you can replace the [tag:architecture] tag to [tag:python] since it is not an architecture question.